# Accessing and Looping through a list in web form asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a public list in the code behind page and it is binding successfully. I want to access it and show the data in design page, data is accessible from list but it is not showing the values of the list items on the page.

```
private void GetAnnouncements()
        {
          var List = (from a in db.ANNOUNCEMENTS
                       orderby a.CREATEDON descending
                       select a).Take(3).ToList();
        }
```

Design Page is as follows

```
<% if (List.Count > 0)
                   {
                       foreach (var item in List)
                       {%>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 faq-wrapper">
                        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
                            <h3>ANNOUNCEMENTS</h3>
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse11"> <% Convert.ToString(item.HEADING.ToString());%>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapse11" class="accordion-body collapse">
                                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                                        <div class="answer"><%  item.CREATEDON.ToString(); %> here</div>
                                        <p>
                                            <%  item.ANNOUNCEMENT1.ToString(); %>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <%}
                   } %>
```

Comment: are you using MVC and how List is accessible in your view or aspx page? And also you don't need to use this `if (List.Count > 0)`

Comment: Have you tried to use the debugger to see what happens? You can add breakpoints in both your code-behind and your html code

Comment: I am working on web forms not MVC and I have debugged and everything is working fine but the data inside the list is not showing on web page using this syntax <%  item.ANNOUNCEMENT1.ToString(); %>. Her i am still stuck.... :(

Comment: I have to use if (List.Count > 0) because I want to show the div if the list contains the data.